# Sharedpreferences in firebase database

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, sharedpreferences

is it possible to write the data that is saved in SharedPreferences and save and read in the firebase database? In my project, I would like to save the values ​​of the players' currencies in their accounts, I already managed to do this with Sharedpreferences, but if I uninstall the app and log in again the data (currency values) is no longer there.

Simply put, I would like to save the data that is in Sharedpreferences in the firebase database so that users can save their coins.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds totally possible, given that both have an API that allows reading and writing. Are you struggling with anything specific here? Or just asking whether it's worth a shot. If the latter, I'd say it is. :)

Comment: The one thing to keep in mind is what data types you can store in each. Firebase only stores JSON types, which probably means you'll need to come up with a way to serialize/deserialize some types from your shared preferences into/from a string.

Comment: Dear friend, thank you in advance for your attention! So in my case I am creating a Quiz app, and I would like to store the scoring information, in this case the "coins", I managed to store it with Sharedpreference, but now I implemented the login in my project, I'm just confused how I will do to store this information (user currencies) that are saved in Sharedpreferences directly into firebase, so that even if users uninstall the app, logging in again would be there the amount of coins

Comment: You'll want to sign the user in with Firebase Authentication, and then based on the user's ID store information for them in the database. Start with the first of these steps, and take it from there. If you get stuck along the way, post back with the [minimal, complete/standalone code with which we can reproduce your problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and it's likely we can help more concretely.